# Can't iterate through Collection in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

**Update**

It was a stupid typo. I was using `Backbone.Model.extend` for the collection. *facepalm*

---

Trying to iterate through a collection but I think I've populated it incorrectly or something:

```
RecentContent = Backbone.View.extend
    initialize: ->
        @collection = new ContentAPI.ContentCollection()

        @collection.fetch
            success: (collection, response, options) =>
                console.log @collection
                # d {attributes: Object, _escapedAttributes: Object, cid: "c4", changed: Object, _silent: Object…}
                # property `attributes` contains Objects from server

                console.log @collection.models # undefined
                @render()

    #---------------------

    render: ->
        # ERROR: Object has no method 'each'
        @collection.each (model) ->
          console.log model
```

I also noticed that if I tried to bind the `reset` event to `@collection` (instead of render from within the `success` callback), it never seems to get fired.

The collection is very simple:

```
class ContentAPI
    @Content: Backbone.Model.extend {}

    @ContentCollection: Backbone.Model.extend
        url: "/api/content/"
        model: @Content
```

I'm a little new to Backbone so thank you for helping. :)

Comment: You should choose an answer, even though you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your collection is inheriting from the wrong base class.

```
@ContentCollection: Backbone.Model.extend
```

should be

```
@ContentCollection: Backbone.Collection.extend
```

Answer (score 1):

I am no coffeescript expert, but I think your problem is

```
@ContentCollection: Backbone.Model.extend
```

It should be

```
@ContentCollection: Backbone.Collection.extend
```

Also when iterating over your collection's models, use

```
_.each(collection.models, function(model) { console.log(model); });
```

Comment: The Underscore methods are merged onto the collection prototype, so the way he has `each` is fine.

Comment: I thought so. I cant find the documentation on the Backbone site anymore though.